# PHP Threading - Two functions to communicate with one another running at the same time

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to do a little research on Threads in PHP.
In simple i have two While statements that will be running until a condition is met.
These two while statement will need to be able to communicate with one another.

As PHP is, you have to complete one process before moving onto another.

I was to have two processes / programs running that can communicate with one another.

Basically its a `while (socket_read......`
This one reads it status of the socket that changes every couple of seconds.

Another will be writing to the other socket, based on the the response from the socket_read while responses)

Ignore the fact they are sockets, But here is a simple flow chart.
Is this going to be possible?

Current i have the Listen and Write working as separate programs, but i cannot get them to work together without one process finishing first. I thought Threading may be a solution. but can they interact with one another, and do i understand threading correctly?

[image]

The way i understand threading is its like a separate cron job within php
All it will do is follow the instructions given, Errors or Successful it just completes the task you have given it....
almost like a trained monkey with a set of instructions.
Is this the case, there is no way to interact with another thread / mulithread

Comment: Great question, no answers.

Comment: I sacked the project in the end, however am not sure if this may yeld some results for you https://github.com/justincjack/phpthreads

Comment: I wanted to run a local PHP server program without stopping, accepting requests and returning results, so that its data can stay resident in memory for speed. Sockets seem way too complicated. After trying a couple of things I gave up. I'll keep my data in a file and use PHP to access the server, which will read then write the changed data.. The advice I've seen says that the overhead of reading and writing data for each request is not high due to caching. I hope that is true.